# Read <br> from HTML and set as \n in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the HTML code

```
<span class="editableFalse" id="comments">
Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
<br/>
Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
</span>
<textarea id="textareaComments"></textarea>
```

Now I have to fetch the data from this span and set it to a Textarea below it in the same format, ie along with the newline character.

How to achieve that :

```
$("#textareaComments").val($("#comments").text());
```

The above line takes the content from the span but trims off the **br** tag.
I dont get a newline character in the textarea.
Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use replace:

```
$("#textareaComments").val($("#comments").html().replace("<br>", "\n"));
```

Comment: It's awful. Why do you expect the tag html to be `<br>` exactly? Also what if there are other tags?

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = $("#comments").html();
var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
$("#textareaComments").val(str.replace(regex, "\n"));
```

Try the replaces `Br` with `\n` (new line)
And use `.html()` not `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#textareaComments").val($("#comments").clone().find("br").replaceWith("\n").end().text())
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="editableFalse" id="comments">
Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
<br/>
Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
</span>

<textarea id="textareaComments"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also [replaceAll](https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) from jQuery I think

```
$("\n").replaceAll("<br>");
```